# tonic_build add/use external crates like serde

Tags: rust, rust-tonic

I'm trying to use or add an external create like serde, to the build.rs file that tonic_build will use to generate the .rs file from the .proto file.

```
// build.rs file 
    let proto_file = "src/hello/hello.proto";

    tonic_build::configure()
        .build_server(true)
        .out_dir("./src/hello")
        .type_attribute("HelloRequest", "#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]") // adding attributes
        .compile(&[proto_file], &["."])
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("protobuf compile error: {}", e));
```

I can see the attributes are added to the rust file, see below :

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, ::prost::Message)]
pub struct HelloRequest {
    #[prost(string, tag="1")]
    pub id: ::prost::alloc::string::String,
    #[prost(string, tag="2")]
    pub message: ::prost::alloc::string::String,
}
```

but the file doesn't add: `use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};` causing the build to fail. I tried using `server_mod_attribute` but failed. how can I add `use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}` to the auto-generated .rs file using tonic_build?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the full path to the library

`.type_attribute("HelloRequest", "#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]")`